# Visual Studio trying to step into BCL cs files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

When I step through my application and get to a object like List... the debugger looks for a List.cs file somewhere on disk, can't find it and then asks me where it is with some pop up window inside VS. I feel like this was some setting I made in the properties and now I don't know how to turn it off. VS 2012

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered a similar error in VS2013 - in my case it was looking for Stack.cs in the BCL code. The fix for me was to go into  Options > Debugging > General and check the "Enable Just My Code" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You might have "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" enabled (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx). So when you are at List... and trying to step into, it will actually try, but you don't have the sources for that. There is also a new experience for using the .NET framework reference source that was announced recently: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx